# Vuetify Custom Scrollbar

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I tried different custom scrollbars for Vuetify  but failed . Here is one of them which I tried ( I tried it for v-navigation-drawer )

**Vuejs Custom scroll bar**
https://github.serafin.io/vuebar/#installation

**Vuejs Custom scroll bar working example**
https://jsfiddle.net/u94ns8jc/1/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=u94ns8jc

**Vuetify example which is not working**
https://codepen.io/kiranvasi/pen/jxEJqB

```
  <v-navigation-drawer
      :mini-variant.sync="miniVariant"
      :clipped="clipped"
      v-model="drawer"
      fixed
      app  v-bar
      class="el1"
   >
```

Could any one please let me know if you guys are able to make any custom scroll bar for Vuetify  ?  Thank You

Comment: Did you eventually find a working one?

Comment: @WildanMaulanaSyahidillah , Please see the below answer .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gBMjBM

changes:

- wrap 'v-list' (element that cause overflow) into your v-bar element
- removed vue from libraries list
- one row in css

css:

```
.vuebar-element  {
    height: 100%;
```

Comment: Thank You @user1852788 for your answer

Comment: What do you mean by removed vue from libraries list?

Comment: there was double include of vue library: in html section and in "Settings->Javascript->External Scripts/Pens"

Comment: I've tried all this... but all it does is remove the default scrollbar

Answer (score 2):

I am directly modifying the source code.

Under the path:
node_modules\vuetify\src\components\VNavigationDrawer

```
//directly modify the scrollbar style you want.
.v-navigation-drawer__content
  height: 100%
  overflow-y: auto
  overflow-x: hidden !important
  &::-webkit-scrollbar
    width: 1px                                        
  &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
    background: black                                 
    border-radius: 20px
```

Comment: .v-navigation-drawer__content
  height: 100%
  overflow-y: auto
  overflow-x: hidden !important
  &::-webkit-scrollbar
    width: 1px                                       
  &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
    background: black                                
    border-radius: 20px

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, don't stress yourself. Just use only CSS and give yourself rest

**Check out fiddle** https://jsfiddle.net/L3d2tspy/

```
<style>
  /* width */
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
  }

  /* Track */
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #ff2929;
  }

  /* Handle */
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: rgb(255, 219, 219);
  }

  /* Handle on hover */
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #555;
  }
</style>
```